# How to create a sawtooth flange?

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

For connecting parts I am thinking of a sawtooth flange. How could this be done by modifying a face of a cube or a cylinder? Please note there is a fine but important difference between a sawtooth and a simple thread.
In the end would like to 3D print this, however I am aware that it might be challenging for a printer.

[image]

Connected are both parts here. Usually these are plastics. The advantage is, you can still lose the parts by moving B in Z-Direction upwards.

The sawtooth is a special curve which might be achieved by a modulo function.

In the end I can imagine following solution:

1. Create a curve which is defined by a function
2. Apply the curve to a surface or mesh (this is known to me)

The question is: Is 1. supported by Blender?

Comment: I think it would be helpful to add an image of a 'sawtooth flange' for those of us unfamiliar with one.

Comment: Controlling geometry by some mathematical functions is done using Sverchok add-on, there's a big chance this can be done too.